# Spacy multiple NER tags for a single word

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I successfully trained Spacy to recognize some custom named entities.

Let's say that the model successfully recognizes companies (ORG) and fruits (FRUIT).

I would like to get the probability for a word to be each of this entities. Something like:

```
doc = nlp("Apple to ship highest number of new iPhones this fall")

print(getProbabilities(doc))
// [
//   (0,0, 'Apple', [ ['ORG', 0.99], ['FRUIT', 0.01] ])
// ]

doc = nlp("Apple picking machine provides potential future of agriculture")

print(getProbabilities(doc))
// [
//   (0,0, 'Apple', [ ['FRUIT', 0.99], ['ORG', 0.01] ])
// ]
```

Using the technique described [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/881) I can get the score of a particular named entity, but only the most likely one, not the others.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @brunobg Not that I recall

Comment: have you get any solution to handle this issue ?